# jQuery code works on desktop, not in Android

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, mobile

My code moves a picture inside the div using the mouse. It works in a web browser on Windows. How can I change it so that it works in Android?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $bg = $('.bg-img'),
    //data = $('#data')[0],
    elbounds = {
      w: parseInt($bg.width()),
      h: parseInt($bg.height())
    },
    bounds = {
      w: 1920 - elbounds.w,
      h: 1080 - elbounds.h
    },
    origin = {
      x: 0,
      y: 0
    },
    start = {
      x: 0,
      y: 0
    },
    movecontinue = false;

  function move(e) {
    var inbounds = {
        x: false,
        y: false
      },
      offset = {
        x: start.x - (origin.x - e.clientX),
        y: start.y - (origin.y - e.clientY)
      };

    //data.value = 'X: ' + offset.x + ', Y: ' + offset.y;

    inbounds.x = offset.x < 0 && (offset.x * -1) < bounds.w;
    inbounds.y = offset.y < 0 && (offset.y * -1) < bounds.h;

    if (movecontinue && inbounds.x && inbounds.y) {
      start.x = offset.x;
      start.y = offset.y;

      $(this).css('background-position', start.x + 'px ' + start.y + 'px');
    }

    origin.x = e.clientX;
    origin.y = e.clientY;

    e.stopPropagation();
    return false;
  }

  function handle(e) {
    movecontinue = false;
    $bg.unbind('mousemove', move);

    if (e.type == 'mousedown') {
      origin.x = e.clientX;
      origin.y = e.clientY;
      movecontinue = true;
      $bg.bind('mousemove', move);
    } else {
      $(document.body).focus();
    }

    e.stopPropagation();
    return false;
  }

  function reset() {
    start = {
      x: 0,
      y: 0
    };
    $(this).css('backgroundPosition', '0 0');
  }

  $bg.bind('mousedown mouseup mouseleave', handle);
  $bg.bind('dblclick', reset);
});
```

```css
div.bg-img {
  background-image: url(https://wallpapershome.com/images/pages/pic_h/23843.jpeg);
  background-position: 0 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: blue;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bg-img"></div>
```

Comment: Are you actually using jQuery version 1.7.2? That version is  10 years old

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I also tested with new versions and it does not work